# C, simple way to test multiple values in if statement

Tags: c

I have to parse wav file (plain C) and validate some parameters for passing next functions. One of them is sample rate which is not so short to use bit positions for multiple test in if statement:

```
#define     WAV_ALLOWED_SAMPLE_RATE         (48000)

    if(wavFile.Header.SampleRate != WAV_ALLOWED_SAMPLE_RATE)    /* Sample Rate */
                        return WAV_HDR_CHUNK_FMT_INVALID_SAMPLE_RATE;
```

There is a simple way for testing multiple values that I want to pre-define at design time? Something like this:

```
#define     WAV_ALLOWED_SAMPLE_RATE         (11025 || 22050 || 44100 || 48000)
```

Maybe 2,3 or 4 values, depending on project needs.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Put those values in an array and run a loop over it to find a match.

Comment: What is your question? Do you use a specific API for reading WAV files? Into what format do you read the sample rate from header? What bo you mean with "sample rate which is not **so short** to use bit positions for multiple test in if statement"?

Comment: Create a function to validate that the sample rate is valid, and have it loop over the values in an array of valid rates as suggested by @SameerNaik.  Then call that function with the sample rate that you read from the file to see whether the number is OK.

Comment: I thought so, but I was also looking for a trick :)

Answer (score 2):

In [Wave Format Standard](http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/) sampling rate is a 32-bit integer. So, if you read it into an `int`, you can easily use `if` statements and integer equality comparison. The simplest statement, based on your input:

```
int R = wavFile.Header.SampleRate;

if ( (R != 48000) && (R != 44100) && (R != 22050) && (R != 11025) )
    return WAV_HDR_CHUNK_FMT_INVALID_SAMPLE_RATE;
```

Comment: Depending on sample rate, I have to use a multiple crystal quartz on microcontroller, so that's why I like to #define allowed at compile time. Some values allow (together) multiple sample rates, others don't. Anyhow, seems that array search will be the best, thanks very much.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, perhaps taking a look at how some audio file APIs enumerate sampling rates can also be helpful [link](http://maemo.org/api_refs/5.0/5.0-final/pulseaudio/sample_8h.html)… Anyway, if you have hardware constraints, it's a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define     WAV_ALLOWED_SAMPLE_RATE         (11025 || 22050 || 44100 || 48000)


    if(wavFile.Header.SampleRate != WAV_ALLOWED_SAMPLE_RATE)    /* Sample Rate */
                        return WAV_HDR_CHUNK_FMT_INVALID_SAMPLE_RATE;
```

this code will not go as you want. the value `(11025 || 22050 || 44100 || 48000)` will be interpreted as `1` and thus falsify the if condition...

You could write a simple function that checks for all 4 values, or do it inside your code as is

Comment: Write the function — don't do it inline.  (You might make the function into a `static inline` function; that's a separate discussion.)